# How can i define variable for default values in MariaDB structure?

Tags: mysql, linux, database, mariadb, set

I need to change a lot default values of the DB structure for new entries in MULTIPLE tables to have this new default value in DB I tried to use something like this:

```
SET @money_rename_def := 20*10000;
SET @money_gender_def := 40*10000;

ALTER TABLE `money`     CHANGE `money_rename` `money_rename` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '@money_rename_def', 
                        CHANGE `money_gender` `money_gender` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '@money_gender_def';
```

But the SET prefix does not fork for alter table command. Is there any way how to do this to use pre-defined value so I can only change it once in SET or simillar definition?
I tried to search documentation but maybe just missed it?

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside quoted strings. So I don't know how you expected this to work.

Comment: That is what I wrote, yes. it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic query like this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `tableDefaultSetter`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `tableDefaultSetter`()
BEGIN

    SET @default1 = 20;

    SET @query = concat('ALTER TABLE `ttestt` CHANGE `val` `val` int NOT NULL DEFAULT ', @default1);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END$$
```

**Sample Data:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ttestt;
CREATE TABLE ttestt
(
    id  INT,
    val INT(10) DEFAULT 10
);
INSERT INTO ttestt (id)
VALUES (1);

CALL tableDefaultSetter();

INSERT INTO ttestt (id)
VALUES (1);
SELECT *
FROM ttestt;
```

Result:

```
1,10
1,20
```

So the first item had 10 as default value and second item has been changed to 20. You see that it works.

---

For multiple values, you cannot put multiple queries inside one statement:
[Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html)

> The text must represent a single statement, not multiple statements.

So you can create another procedure for convenience:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `exec_query`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `exec_query`(queryStr TEXT)
BEGIN

    SET @query = queryStr;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END$$


DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `tableDefaultSetter`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `tableDefaultSetter`()
BEGIN

    SET @default1 = 20;
    SET @default2 = 30;
    SET @default3 = 40;
    SET @default4 = 50;

    CALL exec_query(concat('ALTER TABLE `ttestt` CHANGE `val` `val` int NOT NULL DEFAULT ', @default1));
    CALL exec_query(concat('ALTER TABLE `ttestt2` CHANGE `val` `val` int NOT NULL DEFAULT ', @default2));
    CALL exec_query(concat('ALTER TABLE `ttestt3` CHANGE `val` `val` int NOT NULL DEFAULT ', @default3));
    CALL exec_query(concat('ALTER TABLE `ttestt4` CHANGE `val` `val` int NOT NULL DEFAULT ', @default4));

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Use it like this:

```
CALL tableDefaultSetter();
DROP PROCEDURE `tableDefaultSetter`;
DROP PROCEDURE `exec_query`;
```

Comment: Nicely done, thank you. Do I need to use separate procedure for every change or can I just add more variables and query in the one?

Comment: Sorry I fell asleep - it didnt work it says 0 rows affected but it passed - I set multiple DECLAREs and multiple SETs is that ok? Or can you modify your answer to see multiple variables if I did it right? Thank you

Comment: Still the command passed but nothing has changed (0 rows affected) is there any commit command missing or something? But all my commands are executed and commited right away... I use even phpmyadmin ...

Comment: Ok when I executed the procedure it worked finally after your updated code - is there any way to execute it right away and delete after?

Comment: That's ok. That is phpmyadmin trying to show you https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count. Which is 0 because no rows is changed.

Comment: 'is there any way to execute it right away and delete after?' i dont get it. delete what? @Byakugan

Comment: I meant this to be executed immediatelly and dropped after it is ecexuted just like normal ALTER TABLE or UPDATE commands like this: `CALL `tableDefaultSetter`();
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `exec_query`;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `tableDefaultSetter`;`

Comment: Yes, drop it immediately after calling it. It is ok. @Byakugan

Comment: Can you add these three commands I wrote above to your example at the end? I will then accept it, thank you.